# Setting variable in powershell from C#

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I wonder if you could help me being gods of the C# world and all!

I'm pretty new to C# and i think im a bit out of my depth, but i am trying to use C# to create a wpf that will ask the user for parameters and then pass these parameters to my script to perform an install.

At the moment i have it set to click a button to begin the install as that was requested (no idea why) so on button click i have the following.

```
string script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\my\script\path\script.ps1");

using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{

    runspace.Open();
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SiteCode", GlobalVariables.sitecode);
    ps.AddScript(script);
    ps.Invoke();
}
```

My first problem is i need to set the script file location using partially a variable that has been set earlier in the form

Now this i can probably do myself, but calling the powershell script and then setting variables that are used within the powershell script from variables that are declared in the C# form are a bit out of my depth, am i on the right line here? do i look like a complete idiot or should i go bang my head on a tree outside?

Thanks very much in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Don't rely on global variables, define your parameters in the powershell script properly and use `AddParameter()` or `AddArgument()` instead

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the reason for global variables is because in another form it collects data that needs to be recorded and passed throughout the form to determine what happens next and is separate for every time it is run

Comment: Still sounds like the PowerShell script is designed badly :) Can you show the script? Or an equivalent minimal example?

Comment: the powershell script is not the problem, this works completely fine, gathers input at start using read-host as the variables are always different, im not here to try and ammend the powershell script simply to call it